# MacOSX/Windows Kill all Processes Residing in Specified Directory

Tags: windows, macos, shell, batch-file

Is there a way to kill all processes that reside in a given directory with either a shell or a batch script (not just by name, but by path?)?

E.G.
A directory with

```
script.sh
myapp.app
dostuff.command
```

Or one windows:

```
startup.bat
myprog.exe
saver.scr
```

would then kill these specific processes, if running.

Should work on 10.5 and up, and on Windows XP or 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac OS try:

```
killall `basename -a /path/path/*`
```

Comment: Yes, but if I have `script.sh` in a different directory, and it's running, will it kill that too?